# Reduce duplication in NUnit tests for different implementations of interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, nunit

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IStack
{
    int Peek();
    void Push(int i);
}
```

And two implementations:

```
public class LinkedListStack : IStack
{
    public void Push(int x)
    {
     ...
    }

    public int Peek()
    {
     ...
    }
}

public class ArrayStack : IStack
{
    public void Push(int i)
    {
     ...
    }

    public int Peek()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

For my unit tests - I currently have something like this, two files containing the same tests - the only difference being the implementation:

LinkedListStackTest.cs:

```
public class LinkedListStackTest
{
    [Test]
    public void PushToStack()
    {
        //Arrange
        IStack stack = new LinkedListStack();

        //Act
        stack.Push(1);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, stack.Peek());
    }
}
```

ArrayStackTest.cs

```
public class ArrayStackTest
{
    [Test]
    public void PushToStack()
    {
        //Arrange
        IStack stack = new ArrayStack();

        //Act
        stack.Push(1);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, stack.Peek());
    }
}
```

Given the tests for the implementations should be the same - is there a way I can write a single set of NUnit tests that will run against all my implementations of IStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TestCaseSourceAttribute](http://nunit.org/docs/2.6/testCaseSource.html):

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(StackTestCases))]
public void PushToStack(IStack stack)
{
    //Arrange/Act
    stack.Push(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, stack.Peek());
}
```

Implementation of `StackTestCases`:

```
internal class StackTestCases : IEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new LinkedListStack());
            yield return new TestCaseData(new ArrayStack());
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return TestCases.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Please note that the test method will take an `IStack` as a parameter:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(StackTestCases))]
public void PushToStack(IStack stack)
```

...And you can return the different implementations of `IStack` in `TestCases` property of `StackTestCases`:

```
yield return new TestCaseData(new LinkedListStack());
yield return new TestCaseData(new ArrayStack());
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use generics for this purpose with TextFixture attributes having the implementations of your interface.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(LinkedListStack))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ArrayStack))]
class IStack_Contract<T> where T : IStack, new()
{
}
```

You just pass the types to your tests and then they will execute for the respective implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `abstract classes` to achieve this.

First, create an abstract class where you will define all your common/share tests among all your implementations:

```cs
public abstract class MyClassShould
    {
        protected abstract MyInterface Initialize();
    
        protected MyInterface myInterface;
    
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            myInterface = Initialize();
        }
    
        [Test]
        public void FirstTest()
        {
            // do something with myInterface
            // assert results
        }
    }
```

Then create a test class for your Implemenetation1

```cs
public abstract class MyFirstImplementationShould
{
    protected override MyInterface Initialize()
    {
        return new MyFirstImplementation();
    }
}
```

And the same for your Implementation2 which may have extra tests. For example, this implementation has a TTL expiration while the first one doesn't.

```cs
public abstract class MySecondImplementationShould
{
    protected override MyInterface Initialize()
    {
        return new MySecondImplementation();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TtlTest()
    {
        // do something with myInterface
        // assert results
    }
}
```